# 404 not found after changing permalinks to post name in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, customization, file-permissions

Clean default wordpress installation, all fine, just when I change permalinks in wordpress settings to post name, the default wordpress post is given 404 not found. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you please elaborate your question??

Comment: wordpress default set Plain Permalink Settings then i have set Post name Permalink Settings and save change. then after click on page so  is given 404 not found. @JMR

Comment: @JMR Help it's error 404

Comment: Take .htaccess backup make your .htaccess  as .htaccess_1 ....before dng that go to you permalink and click on post....try this n check...hope you have back up

Comment: @JMR i have already done this but no effect 
i have using (amazon EC2)  server